# Expand unbounded walk

Tags: probability, random-walk

For an unbounded walk that goes up or down by one unit with probability p and q=p-1. I have
[image]

that is the probability of being at position -1 at step n

where

$H(s)=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty h_ns^n$

$R(s)=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty r_ns^n$

Assuming $R(s)=(1-4pqs^2)^-\frac{1}{2}$

Given the equation below
$H(s)=\frac{R(s)-1}{2ps}$

How can I expand it to show it is true